# Logic app workflow with service bus: The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized, Ip has been prevented to connect to the endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

i'm trying to develop a stateful logic app workflow with event grid triggers and service bus actions.
[Here is the workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D0PT.png)
The service bus is associated with a VNET with private DNS zone and private endpoint.
i've configured the VNET Integration of the logic app to use the same VNET of the service bus to allow the communication with the logic app and the service bus.
i'm getting the following error when i'm trying to choose the Topic name in the service bus action of the workflow:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnYXI.png)

what i've tried is:

- I set the network in the service bus to public access, only to test if the connection from the logic app would works, and to make sure that the issue is only related to the network, and we are not missing any roles which may the logic app identity need.
  and it was able to connect correctly to the service bus with a public network access
- I already checked that no firewall or NSG roles block the traffic to the service bus.
- I also tried to add the VNET and the SNET of the logic app to the service bus selected networks, but i'm still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with managed Service Bus connector. I added managed connector ips to Service Bus firewall rules and 401 was solved.

So Service Bus was connected to vnet, logic app was connected to same vnet, but connection still goes via connector ips. More from here: [compare-built-in-azure-connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/connectors/compare-built-in-azure-connectors)

How did you check that there was no firewall blocking the connection?